# I get no results when getting data from database, why? java(android studio

Tags: java, database, android-studio

In debugging i can see that it puts everything what i need into the sb StringBuilders, but after the second sb the data just disapears and what was prevously written into the safety_string gets deleted aswell, don't know why.

Here is the whole code, changed it a little since i posted.
Still the same, it's not an out of scope, because the result of getting_kat i do receive, only the result of getting_ter is missing.

```
@Override
public String doInBackground(String... voids) {

    String result="";
    result=getting_kat();
    result+=getting_ter();
    //Making sure it gets put into the safety string
    safety_string=result;
    return result;
}

public String getting_kat(){
    String result="";
    String resultkat = null;
    String connstr = "My connection string";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(connstr);
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        http.setRequestMethod("POST");
        http.setDoInput(true);
        http.setDoOutput(true);


        InputStream ips = http.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";

        //Line by Line reading the data from php

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }

        //String it together into one line
        resultkat = sb.toString();

        //Adding a separator for later split
        result=resultkat+"#KATEGORIA/TERMEK#";

        br.close();
        ips.close();
        http.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        result = e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        result = e.getMessage();
    }
    return result;
}

public String getting_ter(){
    String result="";
    String resultter=null;
    String connstr2 = "My connection string 2";



    try {
        URL url = new URL(connstr2);
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        http.setRequestMethod("POST");
        http.setDoInput(true);
        http.setDoOutput(true);

        InputStream ips = http.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";

        //Line by Line reading the data from php

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }

        //String it together into one line
        resultter = sb.toString();

        result=resultter;

        br.close();
        ips.close();
        http.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        result = e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        result = e.getMessage();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend that you learn the meaning of DRY.  The code repetition is not good.  You should encapsulate the work being done here in a simpler method that you can test on the side and use.  I'm betting the problem has to do with scope, but it's hard to tell without seeing the entire method.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see bug in the code. I cleaned it up a bit for you but it should work both before and after my changes. You don't describe what is actually going wrong with it. In debugging you may just be getting timeout on your connection.

```
public String doInBackground(String... voids) {
    String result = getting_kat() + "#KATEGORIA/TERMEK#" + getting_ter();
    //Making sure it gets put into the safety string
    safety_string = result;
    return result;
}

public String getting_kat() {
    String result = "";
    String connstr = "My connection string";

    try {
        HttpURLConnection http = connect(connstr);
        result = readFromPhp(http);
        http.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        result = e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        result = e.getMessage();
    }
    return result;
}

public String getting_ter() {
    String result = "";
    String connstr = "My connection string 2";

    try {
        HttpURLConnection http = connect(connstr);
        result = readFromPhp(http);
        http.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        result = e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        result = e.getMessage();
    }
    return result;
}

private HttpURLConnection connect(String connstr) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(connstr);
    HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    http.setRequestMethod("POST");
    http.setDoInput(true);
    http.setDoOutput(true);
    return http;
}

private String readFromPhp(HttpURLConnection http) throws IOException {
    // try-with-resources - so you don't have to call close()
    try (
            InputStream ips = http.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips, "UTF-8"), 8)
    ) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        //Line by Line reading the data from php
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }

        //String it together into one line
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not the connection, in debugging when i fill the stringbuilders i can see that it gets the data, but after that, the data just gets deleted. Btw i fixed it, idk how it worked but i just used my safety_string to recieve the data in the while() and it worked, but anyway thanks for everyone's help

Comment: I tried using your code, result in both was nothing, then i introduced two new public strings safety_string_kat and ..._ter, kat works, ter stays empty, so strange, and again when i debug can see that all the data arrives gets put into the string builder and still i get no data at the and, but like i said only when getting_ter is called... fml <3 java

Comment: what do you mean "result is nothing", how is this code called in your program, what class is this part of?

Comment: is this an AsyncTask?